# kong and kong-migrations container error (dns.lua:39)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, api-gateway, kong, konga

I'm just learning to use Kong and I just created containers for the postgres database, kong-migrations, kong, konga and konga-prepare.

But after I built the containers the following error appeared in the kong container and kong-migrations:

> kong  | ERROR: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/tools/dns.lua:39: /etc/hosts: Permission denied
> kong  | stack traceback:
> kong  |         /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/tools/dns.lua:39: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/tools/dns.lua:7>
> kong  |         /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/globalpatches.lua:590: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/globalpatches.lua:4>
> kong  |         /usr/local/bin/kong:6: in function 'file_gen'
> kong  |         init_worker_by_lua:50: in function <init_worker_by_lua:48>
> kong  |         [C]: in function 'xpcall'
> kong  |         init_worker_by_lua:57: in function <init_worker_by_lua:55>

is there any advice on what I should do?

docker-compose files:

```
#SETUP DATABASE POSTGREE
    db:
      container_name: db
      #image: postgres:9.6
      build:
        context: postgres
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USERS: ${KONG_DB_USERNAME}:${KONG_DB_PASSWORD}|${KONGA_DB_USERNAME}:${KONGA_DB_PASSWORD}
        POSTGRES_DATABASES: ${KONG_DB_NAME}:${KONG_DB_USERNAME}|${KONGA_DB_NAME}:${KONGA_DB_USERNAME}
        #POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${KONG_DB_SUPERPAS}|${KONG_DB_SUPERPAS}
      healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "${KONG_DB_USERNAME}"]
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 30s
        retries: 3
      extra_hosts:
        - "$DNS_LOCAL : $IP_LOCAL"
      restart: on-failure
      stdin_open: true
      tty: true
      volumes:
        - ./persist_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      networks:
        - kong-net

    kong-migrations:
      container_name: kong-migrations
      image: kong:latest
      entrypoint: sh -c "sleep 10 && kong migrations bootstrap -v"
      environment:
        KONG_DATABASE: ${KONG_DATABASE}
        KONG_PG_HOST: ${KONG_DB_HOST}
        KONG_PG_DATABASE: ${KONG_DB_NAME}
        KONG_PG_USER: ${KONG_DB_USERNAME}
        KONG_PG_PASSWORD: ${KONG_DB_PASSWORD}
      depends_on:
        - db
      networks:
        - kong-net
      restart: on-failure

# volumes:
#    persist_volume:
# networks:
#    kong-net:
#      external: true

# SETUP KONG GATEWAY
    kong:
      container_name: kong
      image: kong:latest
      environment:
        KONG_DATABASE: ${KONG_DATABASE}
        KONG_PG_HOST: ${KONG_DB_HOST}
        KONG_PG_DATABASE: ${KONG_DB_NAME}
        KONG_PG_USER: ${KONG_DB_USERNAME}
        KONG_PG_PASSWORD: ${KONG_DB_PASSWORD}
        KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG: ${KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG}
        KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG: ${KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG}
        KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG: ${KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG}
        KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG: ${KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG}
        KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN: ${KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN}
      restart: on-failure
      extra_hosts:
        - "$DNS_LOCAL : $IP_LOCAL"
        - "$DNS_BACKEND : $IP_BACKEND"
      ports:
        - $KONG_PROXY_PORT:8000
        - $KONG_PROXY_SSL_PORT:8443
        - $KONG_PROXY_ADMIN_API_PORT:8001
        - $KONG_PROXY_ADMIN_SSL_API_PORT:8444
      networks:
        - kong-net

#SETUP KONGA
    konga-prepare:
      container_name: konga-prepare
      image: pantsel/konga:latest
      command: "-c prepare -a postgres -u postgresql://${KONG_DB_USERNAME}:${KONG_DB_PASSWORD}@db:${KONG_DB_PORT}/${KONGA_DB_NAME}"
      networks:
        - kong-net
      restart: on-failure
      depends_on:
        - db

    konga:
      container_name: konga
      image: pantsel/konga:latest
      restart: always
      networks:
        - kong-net
      extra_hosts:
        - "$DNS_LOCAL : $IP_LOCAL"
        - "$DNS_BACKEND : $IP_BACKEND"
      environment:
        DB_ADAPTER: postgres
        DB_URI: postgresql://${KONG_DB_USERNAME}:${KONG_DB_PASSWORD}@db:${KONG_DB_PORT}/${KONGA_DB_NAME}
        NODE_ENV: production
      volumes:
        - ./konga-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      depends_on:
        - db
      ports:
        - ${KONGA_PORT}:1337

volumes:
  persist_volume:
  konga-data:
  #prometheus_data:

networks:
  kong-net:
    #external: true
```

Dockerfiles:

```
FROM postgres:9.6
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["postgres"]
```

Docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# usage: file_env VAR [DEFAULT]
#    ie: file_env 'XYZ_DB_PASSWORD' 'example'
# (will allow for "$XYZ_DB_PASSWORD_FILE" to fill in the value of
#  "$XYZ_DB_PASSWORD" from a file, especially for Docker's secrets feature)
file_env() {
        local var="$1"
        local fileVar="${var}_FILE"
        local def="${2:-}"
        if [ "${!var:-}" ] && [ "${!fileVar:-}" ]; then
                echo >&2 "error: both $var and $fileVar are set (but are exclusive)"
                exit 1
        fi
        local val="$def"
        if [ "${!var:-}" ]; then
                val="${!var}"
        elif [ "${!fileVar:-}" ]; then
                val="$(< "${!fileVar}")"
        fi
        export "$var"="$val"
        unset "$fileVar"
}

if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
        set -- postgres "$@"
fi

# allow the container to be started with `--user`
if [ "$1" = 'postgres' ] && [ "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
        mkdir -p "$PGDATA"
        chown -R postgres "$PGDATA"
        chmod 700 "$PGDATA"

        mkdir -p /var/run/postgresql
        chown -R postgres /var/run/postgresql
        chmod g+s /var/run/postgresql

        exec gosu postgres "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
fi

if [ "$1" = 'postgres' ]; then
        mkdir -p "$PGDATA"
        chown -R "$(id -u)" "$PGDATA" 2>/dev/null || :
        chmod 700 "$PGDATA" 2>/dev/null || :

        # look specifically for PG_VERSION, as it is expected in the DB dir
        if [ ! -s "$PGDATA/PG_VERSION" ]; then
                file_env 'POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS'
                eval "initdb --username=postgres $POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS"

                authMethod=trust
                if [ "$POSTGRES_USERS" ]; then
                        USERS_ARR=$(echo $POSTGRES_USERS | tr "|" "\n")
                        for USER in $USERS_ARR
                        do
                                USER_PASSWORD=`echo $USER | cut -d: -f2`
                                if [ "$USER_PASSWORD" ]; then
                                        authMethod=md5
                                fi
                        done
                fi

                # check password first so we can output the warning before postgres
                # messes it up
                file_env 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD'
                if [ "$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" ]; then
                        pass="PASSWORD '$POSTGRES_PASSWORD'"
                        authMethod=md5
                else
                        pass=
                fi

                if [ "$authMethod" == "trust" ]; then
                        cat >&2 <<-'EOWARN'
                                ****************************************************
                                WARNING: No password has been set for the database.
                                         This will allow anyone with access to the
                                         Postgres port to access your database. In
                                         Docker's default configuration, this is
                                         effectively any other container on the same
                                         system.

                                         Use "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" to set
                                         it in "docker run".
                                ****************************************************
                        EOWARN
                fi

                { echo; echo "host all all all $authMethod"; } | tee -a "$PGDATA/pg_hba.conf" > /dev/null

                # internal start of server in order to allow set-up using psql-client
                # does not listen on external TCP/IP and waits until start finishes
                PGUSER="${PGUSER:-postgres}" \
                pg_ctl -D "$PGDATA" \
                        -o "-c listen_addresses='localhost'" \
                        -w start

                file_env 'POSTGRES_USER' 'postgres'
                file_env 'POSTGRES_DB' "$POSTGRES_USER"

                psql=( psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 )

                if [ "$POSTGRES_DB" != 'postgres' ]; then
                        "${psql[@]}" --username postgres <<-EOSQL
                                CREATE DATABASE "$POSTGRES_DB" ;
                        EOSQL
                        echo
                fi

                if [ "$POSTGRES_USER" = 'postgres' ]; then
                        op='ALTER'
                else
                        op='CREATE'
                fi
                "${psql[@]}" --username postgres <<-EOSQL
                        $op USER "$POSTGRES_USER" WITH SUPERUSER $pass ;
                EOSQL
                echo

                psql+=( --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" )

                # If you want to create more than one user, please use that variable
                # Variable example: POSTGRES_USERS="user1:user1pass|user2:user2pass|user3:user3password"
                if [ "$POSTGRES_USERS" ]; then
                        USERS_ARR=$(echo $POSTGRES_USERS | tr "|" "\n")
                        for USER in $USERS_ARR
                        do
                                USER_NAME=`echo $USER | cut -d: -f1`
                                USER_PASSWORD=`echo $USER | cut -d: -f2`
                                if [ "$USER_NAME" = 'postgres' ]; then
                                        op='ALTER'
                                else
                                        op='CREATE'
                                fi
                                "${psql[@]}" --username postgres <<-EOSQL
                                        $op USER "$USER_NAME" WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD '$USER_PASSWORD' ;
                                EOSQL
                        done
                fi

                # If you want to create more than one database, please use that variable
                # Variable example: POSTGRES_DATABASES="database1:user1|database2:user2|database3:user3"
                if [ "$POSTGRES_DATABASES" ]; then
                        DATABASES_ARR=$(echo $POSTGRES_DATABASES | tr "|" "\n")
                        for DATABASE in $DATABASES_ARR
                        do
                                DATABASE_NAME=`echo $DATABASE | cut -d: -f1`
                                DATABASE_OWNER=`echo $DATABASE | cut -d: -f2`
                                if [ "$DATABASE_NAME" != 'postgres' ]; then
                                        if [ "$DATABASE_OWNER" ]; then
                                                "${psql[@]}" --username postgres <<-EOSQL
                                                CREATE DATABASE "$DATABASE_NAME" owner "$DATABASE_OWNER" ;
                                                EOSQL
                                                echo
                                        else
                                                "${psql[@]}" --username postgres <<-EOSQL
                                                        CREATE DATABASE "$DATABASE_NAME" ;
                                                EOSQL
                                                echo
                                        fi
                                fi
                        done
                fi

                # If you want to set up initial postgresql.conf parameters, please use that variable
                # Variable example: POSTGRES_CONFIGS="work_mem:15MB|fsync:off|full_page_writes:off"
                if [ "$POSTGRES_CONFIGS" ]; then
                        CONFIGS_ARR=$(echo $POSTGRES_CONFIGS | tr "|" "\n")
                        for CONFIG in $CONFIGS_ARR
                        do
                                CONFIG_NAME=`echo $CONFIG | cut -d: -f1`
                                CONFIG_VALUE=`echo $CONFIG | cut -d: -f2`
                                "${psql[@]}" --username postgres <<-EOSQL
                                        ALTER SYSTEM SET $CONFIG_NAME = "$CONFIG_VALUE" ;
                                EOSQL
                        done
                fi

                echo
                for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
                        case "$f" in
                                *.sh)     echo "$0: running $f"; . "$f" ;;
                                *.sql)    echo "$0: running $f"; "${psql[@]}" -f "$f"; echo ;;
                                *.sql.gz) echo "$0: running $f"; gunzip -c "$f" | "${psql[@]}"; echo ;;
                                *)        echo "$0: ignoring $f" ;;
                        esac
                        echo
                done

                PGUSER="${PGUSER:-postgres}" \
                pg_ctl -D "$PGDATA" -m fast -w stop

                echo
                echo 'PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.'
                echo
        fi
fi

exec "$@"
```

Comment: very hard to even try to help without seeing your code!